# How to always place axis unit in specific tick label position in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

There is a specific way of including units in graphs that I like:
[image: Image from wikipedia]

The image is from Wikipedia, from a page about DIN 461.

The unit is always placed in the second to last axis tick. I want to recreate this kind of behaviour using Matplotlib and I have been successful by modifying the xlabels directly using plt.gca().set_xticklabels(). The use of set_xticklabels is however discouraged, because it stops displaying the proper values once you zoom/pan, do whatever with the plot. Instead, I would like to have a solution, where the second to last tick label is always changed to be a unit.

I tried writing a custom tick label formatter and placing the unit depending on the position. This has not yet worked, due to the different number of ticks that might be shown, depending on the zoom aspect ratio, etc., as well as the fact, that pos is often None, for some reason.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

@FuncFormatter
def my_formatter(x, pos):
    return f"{x}" if pos != 6 else 'Unit'
```

Alternatively, I used ax.set_xticks with some formatting function Formatter: ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks(), Formatter(ax.get_xticks())), but this shows more ticks than I want and also does not change the ticks when zooming, see below:

Example plot:
[image]

Got xticks, replaced the second to last label with the unit and set xticks:

```
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
xtick_labels = list(xticks)
xtick_labels[-2] = "mA"
ax.set_xticks(xticks, labels=xtick_labels)
```

New ticks appear in the corners and x limits change:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Zooming in does not update ticks anymore and the unit label dissapears
[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ax.set_xticks` to set the labels corresponding to the x-values. The x-tick locations can be retrieved using `ax.get_xticks`. Simply get the ticks and change the second to last tick to be what you want. The same can be done for the y-ticks, but my example just shows the x-ticks.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(20)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
xtick_labels = list(xticks)
xtick_labels[-2] = "mA"
ax.set_xticks(xticks, labels=xtick_labels)
```

[image]

Comment: This fixes the ticks to the given positions, so if you zoom in, it will not adjust the ticks to the new x limits of the zoomed view.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you talking about with the interactive viewer? If so, it works for me.

Comment: I updated my question to include your example and what its limitations are

Comment: Okay, I see what you're looking for. But why is that what you want? Why not just put the units in the axis label like a normal plot?

Comment: A professor of mine specifically asked me to do it like this for some courses, as it is the preferred method of denoting the unit according to the DIN 461 norm. Putting the unit in the x/y labels is allowed as well, but often this just looks better. At this point though, it has become more of an exercise in using Matplotlib than anything else, tbh

Answer (score 0):

A method I found that almost completely works, is the following:

Attach a callback to the canvas, so that each time it is drawn, the axis ticks are reset and then rewritten, including the unit, with the set_xticks method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoLocator

x = np.arange(20)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

def set_new_ticks():
    # Reset the labels
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(AutoLocator())
    # Grab the xticks, remove the first and last
    xticks = ax.get_xticks()[1:-1]
    # Create the labels and set the unit
    xtick_labels = list(xticks)
    xtick_labels[-2] = "mA"
    ax.set_xticks(xticks, labels=xtick_labels)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', lambda x: set_new_ticks())
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', lambda x: set_new_ticks())
plt.show()
```

This changes the labels each time you pan. The draw_event callback is not called when zooming, so this needs to be fixed separately, which can be done by connecting the same callback to the button_release_event.

This method still breaks when pressing the **Back to previous view** or the **Reset original view** buttons, but as soon as you click on the axis it is fixed again.

Not perfect, so please add a response if you have better alternatives.